# Unable to Run my Code on Windows Server 2012 X64 as Windows Task

Tags: tfs, server, scheduler, windows-server-2012, tfs-sdk

Let me give you some background what I'm trying to achieve before I call out the problem.

1. Use TFS API to Get Services Work Item.
2. Get all the Open Bugs.
3. Write in excel all the Open Bugs (from step2).
4. Send step3 Excel as Attachment through SMTP.
5. Schedule a Windows Task on Windows Server 2012 and X64 to perform above steps on daily basis.

Problem:

While running step5 I'm not able to write into Excel using OLEDB because of exception"The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine". To resolve this issue, I have build my project Platform Target=X64.

The excel issue is resolved but I'm not able to access TFS API because it is not able to load DLL Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.DataStoreLoader.

Kaleem.

Answer (score 0):

If you get the following error message: "*Could not load file or assembly ‘Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.DataStoreLoader’ or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format*". Please take the solution described in this blog: http://www.tonicodes.net/blog/installing-and-configuring-odata-service-for-tfs-11/